Installing ImageMagick 7 with HEIC support on Centos7/Cloudlinux with cPanel and PHP 7.4 and above
I'm struggling to install the latest version of ImageMagick with HEIC support on a Centos7/Cloudlinux server (which also happens to be running cPanel).
After removing the version of ImageMagick that comes preinstalled I've followed the instructions in this question but when trying to run make on libde265 and libheif it returns the following error:
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
It seems that without these libraries installed setting --with-heic=yes when running ./configure on ImageMagick itself does nothing, it just configures it without HEIC support.
ImageMagick itself otherwise works fine, just without the HEIC support I'm looking for.
Any ideas?
Cheers,
RS

UPDATE 2024-05-25
Based on this (with yum instead of apt) I'm now getting the following output when running configure: https://pastebin.com/19Q9zAd5
Notice line 677. Any ideas on what I should be changing?

Please show the actual commands you ran.

Sorry, code belongs in your question where it can be formatted properly.

@MarkSetchell I forgot to mention, this all took place under /usr/src/.

@MarkSetchell I tried that when I added the previous update, it was far too long. I'll throw it in a paste.

@MarkSetchell here we go: https://pastebin.com/Un50PLAn

I don't use Centos, so I tried via docker. I pulled centos:7 and it ran, but failed to find all the packages you have listed so I have no idea how to proceed. I ran yum update and that worked, but it still can't find any of the packages you installed so I have no idea what I am missing to replicate your procedure.

My suggestion would be to install pkgconfig to help ImageMagick find libheif. Failing that, try to find libheif in your filesystem, with find / -name "*lib*heif*" and set HEIF_CFLAGS and HEIF_LIBS when running ./configure.

And/or, find the pkgconfig file that got installed with libde265 and/or libheif (it will be called something like libheif.pc) and ensure you append the containing directory to your PKG_CONFIG_PATH

You must have done a lot more than you show in your question. I found I had to do yum groupinstall 'Developer Tools' and install cmake3 from source because the system version was too old. Please put all the code necessary to reproduce your issues in your question, rather than referring to some Debian stuff which is not very close to Centos in this respect.
